# What is causing this "file import" error in Akeneo?

Tags: import, data-import, akeneo, pim

I have the latest version of Akeneo connected to a Magento 2.3.5 instance and upon importing, I get the following error: File import is not enabled.

[image: Akeneo file import error]

I have checked to see that the file import is enabled on all import profiles in the admin panel. Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: This is about enabling the file import into magento connector configuration setup.